# Jenkins needs restart before bitbucket hook works

Tags: linux, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, system-administration

Why do I need to restart Jenkins before my bitbucket Jenkins hook works?

Every time I add a new job to Jenkins, I have to restart Jenkins before the bitbucket jenkins hook works.

Does somebody knows why?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I just have to wait a moment to see the job.

I hope this help somebody.